# Implementing Continuous Wavelet Transform

Tags: wavelet, transform

I need to implement the discretized continuous wavelet transform from scratch. Could someone please point me to useful papers and references available online for this?

Comment: Better suited for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?

Comment: what'sa *discrete* continuous wavelet transform?  seems sorta self-contradictory.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87501/54347 This answer may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1D, some of the standard references are:

- [Continuous wavelet transform with arbitrary scales and $O({N})$ complexity](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168402001408), A. Muñoz and R. Ertl\'e and M. Unser, Signal Processing, 2002
- [A fast approximation to the continuous wavelet transform with applications](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ACSSC.1997.679101), Berkner, K. and Wells, R. O., Jr., 1997, Proc. Asilomar
- [Fast Quasi-Continuous Wavelet Algorithms for Analysis and Synthesis of One-Dimensional Signals](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036139995288010), Maes, S. H., 1997, SIAM J. Appl. Math.
- [Comparison of algorithms for the fast computation of the continuous wavelet transform](http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=1021580), Vrhel, M. J. and Lee, C. and Unser, M. A., 1996, Proc. SPIE
- [Fast algorithms for discrete and continuous wavelet transforms](https://doi.org/10.1109/18.119724), Rioul, O. and Duhamel, P., 1992, IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory

For a GPU implementation:

- [Effiziente Berechnung der FWT auf Grafikkarten](http://www.fim.uni-passau.de/fileadmin/files/lehrstuhl/sauer/geyer/BA_MA_Arbeiten/BA-MaltanRichard-201404.pdf), Richard Maltan, Bachelorarbeit, 2014